# Can anyone please determine integral below?

Tags: prime-numbers

***I was creating a paper on P.N.T but I stucked here so,***[image]

Comment: I'm unclear on how your evaluating the derivative of this step function and then trying to find an anti derivative with a Stieltjes integral of some kind.

Comment: @Ethan That's why its difficult for me, however one may use Dirac delta function, (though I have a very less knowledge of it !)

Comment: Your comment have nothing to do with solution @Ethan ,

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of distributions we may add the jumps at all the prime numbers $p$ to get :
$$R'(t)=\sum_{p\;\text{prime}}\left[\frac{\ln(p)}{p}\delta(t-p)\right]-\frac 1t$$
(since a term $\dfrac{\ln(p)}{p}$ is added to $R(t)$ each time $t$ 'crosses a prime $p$')

We may then conclude that (restraining the integral to the primes $\,p\le x$) :

\begin{align}
\int_0^x \frac {t\,R'(t)}{\ln(t)}dt&=\sum_{p\le x}\left[\int_0^x\frac{\ln(p)}{p}\frac t{\ln(t)}\delta(t-p)\,dt\right]-\int_0^x\frac t{t\,\ln(t)} dt\\
&=\sum_{p\le x}\frac{\ln(p)}{p}\frac {p}{\ln(p)}-\operatorname{li}(x)\\
\\
\int_0^x \frac {t\,R'(t)}{\ln(t)}dt&=\pi(x)-\operatorname{li}(x)\\
\end{align}
from the definition of the [prime-counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) $\pi(x)$ and the [logarithmic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Integral_representation) $\;\operatorname{li}(x)$.